# Как записать в файл json текст?

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

Есть код на питоне, но он работает не так как я хочу. Мне нужно чтобы он записывал в файл слова (По типу Hello). Прога тоже их записывает, но удаляя 1 блок(intents), а мне нужно без удаления. Короче говоря, записать без потерь. Код:

```
import json

with open("my.json") as file:
    F = json.load(file)

mb = input("")
for p in F["intents"]:
    p["responses"].append(mb)
    with open("my.json", "w") as file:
        json.dump(p, file)
```

И вот `my.json` файл:

```json
{"intents": [
  {"tag": "evil", 
  "responses": ["Hello"]}]
}
```

Comment: так ты пишешь p, а надо F

Comment: Попробовал, ничего не изменилось:(

Answer (score 3):

Порядок действий:

1. Прочитать файл, разобрать json
2. Обратиться к нужному списку внутри прочитанного объекта, добавить значение с помощью `append`
3. Записать измененные данные в файл (весь объект данных, не только измененный список)

```
import json

with open("my.json") as file:
    data = json.load(file)

mb = input()
data["intents"][0]["responses"].append(mb)  # Добавляем слово в список responses

with open("my.json", "w") as file:
    json.dump(data, file, indent=2)
```

Пример результата (ввели слово `test`):

```json
{
  "intents": [
    {
      "tag": "evil",
      "responses": [
        "Hello",
        "test"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
F.get("intents", None)[0].get("responses", None) = list(mb)
```

Comment: 1 - тут нет смысла использовать get вместо обращения через квадратные скобки (преимущество квадратных скобок: при отсутствии ключа get вернет None, а потом уже при обращении к None по индексу вылетит TypeError, а при обращении через квадратные скобки сразу вылетит KeyError - сразу будет понятно, что ключа нет, а не None откуда-то внезапно вылез). 2 - `list(mb)` превратит введенное слово в список из букв этого слова, я думаю, что это не то что требуется в задаче.

Comment: Можно и в get прописать None.

Comment: get и так по умолчанию возвращает None, если ключа нет, поэтому нет смысла прописывать None вторым параметром get. А лучше не возвращать None, а падать с KeyError при отсутствии ключа. Почитайте мой комментарий выше еще раз. Ну и ошибку с обернутой в list строкой не исправили.